# Why does this action look different after being appended?

Tags: animation, append, actions

I'm trying to import an action from an old project into a new project. When I do so, the animation just doesn't look right.

Here's the action in the old project:

[image: The action in its original .blend file.]

And here it is in the new project:

[image: The action after being appended to a new .blend file.]

Note how the animation follows roughly the same beats, but some movements appear to be inverted. What's causing this?

You can find the .blend files [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1imHIiDGlMQqhbjjyTaWpaIWeRXOUn4gn/view?usp=sharing). Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the same model to begin with, is the rig exactly the same?

Comment: Probably because you need to rotate the bones on their Y axis? Ctrl R in Edit mode

Comment: @moonboots hit ctrl + r, rotated the bones by 180, that fixed it! thank you so much! i didn't know i could do that.

Comment: @L0Lock the armature is exactly the same, i was trying to figure out how to transfer the animation from one project to another. it's resolved now!

Comment: @moonboots I have one more issue now, the action that I had already made in the new project now has [twisted arms](https://i.imgur.com/cs8DdSf.png). Is there a way for me to fix this action so that the bones are properly rotated?

Comment: it may be a problem of IK constraint: try to tweak the Pole Angle, if it doesn't work please share your file

Comment: @moonboots I don't have any bone constraints in this one, [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KZcYFHqvGIIvvrOvo9_i6d_4kL8KH7d6/view?usp=sharing) are my project files both before and after rotating the bones on their y axis.

Comment: Actually if you copy paste the right pose to Paste Pose Flipped the left arm will be symmetrical to the right arm, so the arm bones seem to be correctly rotated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140134/discussion-between-meattail-and-moonboots).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rotate the bones on their Y axis: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> in *Edit* mode.

As you can see in the latest version you share, the bones orientations are not the same, you need to make sure that they are the same if you want the action to act the same way on both the 2 armatures. For example for the tail you need to rotate 180° in order to align with the other one:

[image]